# Need help parsing a csv file and gathering the information together

Tags: java, csv

The csv file I am trying to parse contains various samples with several lines per sample. For example, there are 10 lines with the same sample name "S1" and I need to get the CT value from each line. I am trying to combine the CT values (differentiated by the Target Name) to create a Sample class for each sample. I am able to parse the file, but I am having a hard time getting it to loop through and gather the right data.

The constructor for my Sample class has 11 parameters, one for the sample name and 10 for the CT values.

After thinking about it for a long time I tried gathering all of the information I need in an ArrayList of String arrays. This didn't help too much because I now don't know how to gather the information together to create and instance of my Sample class. Here's what I tried:

```
    public void parseCSV(){

    String line = "";
    String csvSplitBy = ",";

    try
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("/Users/Neema/Desktop/testData.csv"));

        String[] data;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            data = line.split(csvSplitBy);

            if (data.length > 0 && data[0].equals("Well"))
            {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine())
                {
                    line = scanner.nextLine();
                    data = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                    if (data.length > 4)
                    {
                        String sampleName = data[3];
                        String dataType = data[4];
                        String ctValue = data[11];
                        String[] gatheredData = {sampleName, dataType, ctValue};
                        parsedData.add(gatheredData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the csv file, [testData2](http://www.filedropper.com/testdata2)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the problem that your Sample class has a constructor with more parameters than you have data from the .csv?

Comment: Not necessarily. Each sample has 10 data points, but it comes off of the instrument with one data point per line for each sample. If all of the data points were on a single line I wouldn't have much of a problem, but getting the data from different lines and associating it to the same sample name is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand. What you need is a Sample Factory.

```
class SampleFactory {

     String sampleName;
     List<TargetAndValue> sampleList;


     SampleFactory(String sampleName)
     {
       this.sampleName = sampleName;
     }

     class TargetAndValue{
         String dataType;
         String ctValue;
         TargetAndValue(dataType, ctValue)
         {
            this.dataType = dataType;
            this.ctValue = ctValue;
         }
     }

     void addCtValue(dataType, ctValue) { //Instantiate a new TargetAndValue class }

     Sample build(){ //Construct your Sample here }

}
```

Than what you need is a list of SampleFactories. As you parse each line you search for the SampleFactory that has the right sampleName, and add your data point. Once you have parsed everything use your factory to spit out your Sample objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was able to implement this and its working well.

Comment: Wooo!! I'm helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a map. For example

```
 public void parseCSV(){

  String line = "";
  String csvSplitBy = ",";
  Map<String,List<String>> mapofSamples = new TreeMap<>();    // import java.util.Map; import java.util.TreeMap;
  try
  {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("/Users/Neema/Desktop/testData.csv"));

      String[] data;

      while (scanner.hasNextLine())
      {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        data = line.split(csvSplitBy);

        if (data.length > 0 && data[0].equals("Well"))
        {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                line = scanner.nextLine();
                data = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                if (data.length > 4)
                {   
                    if(!mapofSamples.containsKey(data[3])){    // if the map does not already contain the sample name add this name and a list with the value
                       mapofSamples.put(data[3],new ArrayList(){{add(data[11]);}} );
                    }
                    else{
                       mapofSamples.get(data[3]).add(data[11]); // else just add the value to the corresponding sample names value list
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(String key: mapofSamples.keySet()){      // check if it prints the right keys and values
        System.out.println("sample :" + key);
        System.out.println("values :" + mapofSamples.get(key));
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: I went with the sample factory answer, but I believe this would have worked as well. Thanks for the response!